# Change the name of a theme-folder on wordpress mu network?

Tags: wordpress

I'm hosting a wordpress network. It has a bunch of themes named "Nacka blue" "Nacka green" etc.

The folders the themes are in are also named this.(including the spaces unfortunately).

I recently upgraded wordpress to 3.4.1, and it somehow inteprets the links to the screenshots of the images differently. it's now

```
wp-content/themes/Nackablue/screenshot.png
```

rather than the previous

```
wp-content/themes/Nacka blue/screenshot.png
```

I want to rename the theme-folder, but ofcourse, then the blogs using the theme will believe that the theme is missing and revert to the default theme, also they apparently drop the header-image. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving it like this:

Duplicating all themes with new names
Activate the new themes
Manually change all the themes to the new ones.
Deleting the old themes.

Make sure to save and keep track of any custom headers/backgroundcolors etc. As theese will be reset to default.